# Why does react native app crash after confirming upi payment with razorpay?

Tags: react-native, razorpay, upi

I am trying to implement UPI payment in my react native app but my app is crashing on successful payment. I have already implemented card payment and that works perfectly but the app is crashing in the case of UPI payment, even though I am getting a successful payment alert. I am using the customui SDK for implementing Razorpay payments. I am not getting any kind of exception or error so I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Razorpay Code

```
    var options = {
        currency: 'INR',
        key_id: 'test_key',
        amount: this.props.total,
        vpa:this.state.upi,
        contact: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        email: 'XXXXXXXXX',
        method: 'upi'          
      }
      Razorpay.open(options).then((data) => {
        // handle success
        alert(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`);
        console.log(`Success: ${data.razorpay_payment_id}`)
      }).catch((error) => {
        // handle failure
        alert(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`);
        console.log(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`)
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below to your proguard configuration:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn com.razorpay.**
-keep class com.razorpay.** {*;}
-optimizations !method/inlining/
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {   public void onPayment*(...); }
```

This will cause Razorpay references in your code to not be minified.

This will solve the issue if anyone faces this.

Comment: I pasted these in proguard-rules.pro.The app is still crashing, unfortunately.

Comment: any workaround found ?